# My tableView rows load slowly when my iOS 7 app is launched the first time but fast during additional launches. Is there a fix for this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, parse-platform

Completed my first app and after a week of going through my code cleaning up I'm happy to see 6mb memory use and 0% cpu. I'm guess that's a good thing from what I've read.

Anyway one thing I've noticed is that if I delete my app from the simulator or my actual iPhone and launch the app the rows load slowly. Some times 2 will load together, sometimes one but they never just load at the same time all in one go.

However once they're loaded I don't experience this issue again when I launch the app from that moment. I use parse for all my backend work and here is how my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks.

**Here is my code**

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache
    // first to fill the table and then subsequently do a query
    // against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        [query setCachePolicy: kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];
    }

    [query whereKey:@"active" equalTo:@1];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;
}

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView]) {
            return [searchResults count];
        } else {
            return [[self objects] count];
        }

    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                            object:(PFObject *)object {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [[self tableView] dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        PFObject *current;
        if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView]) {
            current = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
            current = [[self objects] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        PFFile *userImageFile = current[@"image"];
        [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [[cell imageView] setImage:image];
            [[cell textLabel] setText:[current valueForKey:@"name"]];
            [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[current valueForKey:@"notes"]];
        }];

        return cell;
    }
```

What could be going on? Is there a fix for this?

**First time I load the app after deletion I get the following error come up a few times with slow loading rows:**

> 2014-03-11 01:50:17.161 MissingPeople[87755:690f] Could not save HTTP
>   response body to /Users/londonguy/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/0E119F55-C3CE-4827-AE64-25933460E2ED/Library/Caches/Parse/PFFileCache/bc6cb3bd-83bd-4518-afe7-b7a18f11131e-image.jpg:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 516.)" UserInfo=0x11f35120
>   {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/londonguy/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/0E119F55-C3CE-4827-AE64-25933460E2ED/tmp/PFHTTPCommand0x11f331b0,
>   NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Move ), NSFilePath=/Users/londonguy/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/0E119F55-C3CE-4827-AE64-25933460E2ED/tmp/PFHTTPCommand0x11f331b0,
>   NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/londonguy/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/0E119F55-C3CE-4827-AE64-25933460E2ED/Library/Caches/Parse/PFFileCache/bc6cb3bd-83bd-4518-afe7-b7a18f11131e-image.jpg,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x11f35050 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   File exists"}

**How searchResults is created**

```
#pragma mark - Search bar code

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [[self objects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

**Init and viewWillAppear**

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // This table displays items in my People class on parse.com
        [self setParseClassName: @"People"];
        [self setPullToRefreshEnabled: NO];
        [self setPaginationEnabled: YES];
        [self setObjectsPerPage: 10];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self showProgressHUD];
    [self loadObjects];

    // Create a new view to a specific size
    UIView *loadMoreView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 718, 239, 50)];
    [loadMoreView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    // Make this view the footer of my tableview
    [[self tableView] setTableFooterView: loadMoreView];

    // Create the button
    UIButton *loadMoreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    // Set the size of the button to fill up the view it's within
    [loadMoreButton setFrame: loadMoreView.bounds];

    // Set the title and colour
    [loadMoreButton setTitle:@"Load More..." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [loadMoreButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // Connect up an action to trigger loadNextPage method when button is tapped
    [loadMoreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadMoreButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Add this new button to the loadMoreView
    [loadMoreView addSubview:loadMoreButton]; // add the button to bottom view
}
```

**Further Updates:**

I have added a place holder image that shows up instantly until images from backend download. I've also take the line that set the title and subtitle of the cell out of the block. Now the page loads much faster. The original reason for putting those lines in the block was because I wanted the image, title and subtitle to load at the same time. This doesn't matter now with that placeholder image set. How ever I'm still getting the cocoa error 516.

**Here is the new code:**

```
PFFile *userImageFile = current[@"image"];
[userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:image];
}];
[[cell textLabel] setText:[current valueForKey:@"name"]];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[current valueForKey:@"notes"]];
```

Comment: The answer likely has more to do with `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, and how `searchResults`/`[self objects]` are created than it does anything you posted.

Comment: I only use viewWillAppear, [self objects] is a PFQueryTableViewController method that just holds an NSArray of currently loaded objects. SearchResults isn't created until I use my search bar. I've added most of that controller code plus the error that's coming up.

Comment: @nhgrif Issue was exactly where you said it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of points for someone just completing a first app.   .... Your cache setting (kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork) is causing the table to be loaded piecemeal, if you do not like this behaviour just use the default which means its empty until the full tableview can be displayed.

Cocoa 516 is a file already exist error, in all probability - you are do not clear out your tmp folder when you exit so when you try to build your cache from scratch the jpg files are already existing. It may also be indicative of other errors that are network related but with the absence of another error message that is probably remote.

With regards to the slow loading - it can't be helped if your network connection is slow what you can do is to separate the initial viewload from getting the data from the network this means some changes in your structure.

Comment: Done some research and this article: [link](https://www.parse.com/questions/cache-policy-help-and-best-practice) helped slightly. I went straight to my tmp folder and found the cached images complained about in the error and deleted them. Deleted my app and ran it again to see if I'd still get the errors. When the app is built a new tmp folder and hierarchy is created as each error is showing I see the cached image file created in the tmp folder. Not sure how to sort this one out.

Comment: Maybe you should report it to PARSE, I googled 516 and PFQuery and got this:  https://parse.com/questions/cocoa-error-512-when-loading-a-picture. ... images are outside the JSON file that goes up and down just could be that the routines are just not coded to handle duplicate file images very well.

Comment: My app is working much better but just wondering if this type of error would get my app rejected. Also if there is a way to stop it from showing up?

Comment: I usually make sure that my apps are very clean before submitting to Apple, even then, I missed a bug  before that I thought was not important, it took me a month and Apple made sure it was fixed before accepting the app.  That was v 3.0 of the app, the bug actually existed in V 2.0 and the review did not notice it.

Comment: The problem was my loadObjects method was causing some strange behaviour behind the scenes. The error is now gone but the main reason I had this method in my viewWillAppear was so that when I returned to main tab from another the main list of people would refresh. I've solved this problem using notification centre but would prefer to use delegation and have a new question I'm about to post.